# mongoDB query compare two keys in an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to write a query that returns keys and objects where a condition is met. Say I have a document that looks like this.

```
page1:{
key1:100,
k2:50,
k3:10
}
page2:{
    k1:50,
    k2:100,
    k3:10
}
```

In this instance I would like to return k1 and k2 from the page 2 object, because k2 is greater than k1.
This is what my query looks like;

```
    collection.find({$or:[
    {page1.k2:{$gt:page1.k1}},
    {page2.k2:{$gt:page2.k1}}
]})
```

It's returning an empty list of docs, but I know the condition is true in some instances. Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mongo version is >= 3.6 you can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#expr).

Your example document has "key1" in page1 and "k2" in page2.

PyMongo needs everything in quotes.

Try:

```py
coll.find({
    '$or': [
        {'$expr': {'$gt': ['$page1.k2', '$page1.key1']}},
        {'$expr': {'$gt': ['$page2.k2', '$page2.k1']}}
    ]
})
```

Returns (with only your 1 sample doc in the collection):

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5ec735d39f4bd37cc16b4083'),
 'page1': {'k2': 50, 'k3': 10, 'key1': 100},
 'page2': {'k1': 50, 'k2': 100, 'k3': 10}}
```